# How to load one specific WP plugin when loading using SHORTINIT

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We have WP loading successfully using SHORTINIT to power part of our API, using the below code. However, we also need to be able to load one WP plugin and seem to be unable to do so.

This part works great (on WordPress 4.9.8):

```
    define('SHORTINIT', true);
    require_once $wploadpath;
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/class-wp-user.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/class-wp-roles.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/class-wp-role.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/class-wp-session-tokens.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/class-wp-user-meta-session-tokens.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/formatting.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/capabilities.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/user.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/meta.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/vars.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/kses.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/rest-api.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/pluggable.php';
    wp_cookie_constants();
```

We also are able to load our Theme functions successfully:

```
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/../wp-content/themes/ourtheme/functions.php';
```

However, the same method for plugins doesn't seem to work:

```
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/../wp-content/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-pro/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-pro.php';
```

We've tried including more of the includes but doesn't help:

```
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/plugin.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/shortcodes.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/post-thumbnail-template.php';  
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/l10n.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/post.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/class-wp-post.php';
    require_once $wpincludepath . '/post-template.php';
```

No errors are generated, but we just get no plugin capability. Is it possible to load WP plugins at all using SHORTINIT? If so, how? Thanks!